# How to position a div at the bottom of a table cell?

Tags: html, css

I'm tired of searching and not being able to accomplish this: **1 label at top left of a cell and the content at the bottom center.** Trying to achieve this, I'm using 2 divs inside a TD, but I don't mind changing that as long as I can achieve the goal.

1. I don't know the size of the labels (they can be translated into different languages and therefore taking different sizes).
2. The original table will be taking half of an A4 Portrait in height. It's 7 (row) * 5 (columns) (with the exception of 1 single cell in the middle of it that I use rowspan="2")
3. I've tried the "set the parent to `position: relative` and make the container `position: absolute; bottom: 0`" solution and I can't make it work.
4. Basically, I want to have 1 label set to the `top left` and the content in the `bottom middle` of the cell.
5. The 950px width is for printing purposes.

Here is a jsfiddle link to exemplify my problem. 
http://jsfiddle.net/o1L31qwu/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a flexbox solution that will handle arbitrarily-sized `.label` and `.content`: http://jsfiddle.net/5kzzgkgr/.

The content of the cell should be placed in a wrapper `div`:

```
<td>
     <div>
         <div class="label">This Label is large / and divided [eph] really large label.And some more text, text, text, and more text.....<br /><br /></div>
         <div  class="content">BOTTOM</div>
     </div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.tableClass td{
    height: 0px;
}

.tableClass div:only-of-type {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work with the `div:only-of-type` spec, but I added 1 class to each div wrapper and it worked like a charm.  I don't really know why, but I liked your solution better. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

change your CSS like this:

```
.tableClass {
    width: 950px;
    table-layout: auto;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;    
}

.tableClass td{
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.label{position:relative; margin:4px; margin-bottom:30px /* adjust to bottom size */; }
.content{width:100%; position:absolute; bottom:1px; left:0; background:#fc0; margin:0; text-align:center;}
```

I have added a background color for visualization purposes, but of course you'll need to edit at will . [See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xxdkqxwa/)